# Isotope JS Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need a bit of help with a Js error I am getting please:

> Uncaught TypeError: $portfolio.isotope is not a function

```
  
//ISOTOPE FUNCTION - FILTER PORTFOLIO FUNCTION

    $portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
    $portfolio.isotope({
        itemSelector : 'li',
        layoutMode : 'fitRows'
    });
    $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
    $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
        $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Has isotope loaded before you run this script?

Comment: Yes, Isotope has loaded. But on the page itself it shows no errors, only on pages without the isotope gallery.

Comment: So you are running this on pages that don't contain any `.portfolio-items` elements?

Comment: yes... as the Js is in a global script which is linked on all pages

Comment: Wrap your code form line 2 down in a length check: `if ($portfolio.length) { ...rest of your code... }` this will prevent it from running on pages that don;t contain the required elements

Comment: Speechless! Thank  you so much! Works a treat!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want your script to run on pages that don't contain the required elements (`.portfolio-items`), you can run your script conditionally based on the `length` property of your element collection stored in `$portfolio`:

```
$portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');

if ($portfolio.length) { // if 'length' is non zero. Enter block...

    $portfolio.isotope({
        itemSelector : 'li',
        layoutMode : 'fitRows'
    });
    $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
    $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
        $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });

}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, tried your solution but still having the same error. What could be other possible reasons for this error?

Comment: @SachinVairagi You would also get the `Uncaught TypeError: $portfolio.isotope is not a function` error if you haven't loaded the isotope library correctly. Check the Network section of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have raised new question and posted my codes as well, can you please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292697/typeerror-container-isotope-is-not-a-function