# TypeError: $container.isotope is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope, imagesloaded

Probably it could be duplicate question but I have tried every solution I found, I am newbie with **imagesLoaded** , can anyone please help to get rid out of it?

The scripts I have included is in following order -

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='{{asset('assets/includes/js/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')}}'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='{{asset('assets/includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min330a.js')}}'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='{{asset('assets/js/imagesloaded.js')}}'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='{{asset('assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.js')}}'></script>
```

And the javascript code I have -

```
jQuery( function() {
    /* ======= Masonry Grid System ======= */
    var $container = $('.posts-masonry');
    if ($container.length) {
        $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
            $container.isotope({
                layoutMode: 'masonry',
                transitionDuration: '0.3s'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Is there any other script I am missing? Please suggest.

Comment: You aren’t loading the isotope plugin: https://isotope.metafizzy.co

Comment: Which files I should include? all 3 JS - https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/tree/master/js

Comment: Look at the "Install" section of the documentation: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/#install - `isotope.pkgd.min.js` is probably what you want.

Comment: Okay, let me check it Turmip..